# Getting image from my dictionary is causing an "unrecognized selector" error

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview, unrecognized-selector

I'm parsing JSON file in iOS and I'm getting elements in a tableview but when I created (`prepareForSegue`) to get tableview element I can't get image and I get this error:

> unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa3427c5b20 2016-05-05 05:08:43.287 MovieClub[4845:212195] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString size]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa3427c5b20'

in this line of code:

```
self.postt.image =[self.actuatlitDetail objectForKey:@"poster_240x342"];
```

Comment: what is  poster_240x342 is it name of image or url ?

Comment: Please share more code so we can help you out.

Comment: the objective c don't accept it

Comment: any other solution

Comment: .m
self.prepTimeLabel.text = [self.actuatlitDetail objectForKey:@"original_title"];
     self.postt.imageWithName =[self.actuatlitDetail objectForKey:@"poster_240x342"];

Comment: self.postt.image =[UIImage imageWithName:[self.actuatlitDetail objectForKey:@"poster_240x342"]];
 if poster_240x340 image exist in your project

Comment: The error means that `[self.actuatlitDetail objectForKey:@"poster_240x342"]` is returning an `NSString` but your code assumes it is a `UIImage`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load image from remote server on the UIImageView in iphone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905497/how-to-load-image-from-remote-server-on-the-uiimageview-in-iphone)

Comment: `self.postt.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.actualtitDetail objectForKey:@"poster_240x342"]]]];` that's because your image is a string, you have to fetch the actual image data and convert it to an `UIImage` before assigning it to the `image` property of your `UIImageView`. It crashes because it tries to call the method `size` of a `UIImage`, but as it is a `NSString` with no such method, it fails.

Comment: @wassimwess I suggest you to put break-point and check. Also add NSLogs. If it's URL string then edit question add info related to the same (Ex: http://www.domain.com/image/poster_240x342.particular extension)

Answer (score 1):

If `[self.actuatlitDetail objectForKey:@"poster_240x342"]` returns NSURL you can use

```
NSURL *imageURL = [self.actuatlitDetail objectForKey:@"poster_240x342"];
self.postt.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL]];
```

If it is NSString then represent URL then

```
NSString *imageURLString = [self.actuatlitDetail objectForKey:@"poster_240x342"];
self.postt.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURLString]]];
```

You can load image in background

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
dispatch_queue_t aQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(aQueue, ^{
    NSURL *imageURL = [weakSelf.actuatlitDetail objectForKey:@"poster_240x342"];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL]];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        weakSelf.postt.image = image;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

its url value of actuatlitDetail, get the below code,

```
NSString *imageurl = [self.actuatlitDetail objectForKey:@"poster_240x342"];
NSString *encodedUrlString = [imageurl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString: encodedUrlString];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
UIImage *imag = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
self.postt.image = imag;
```

hope its helpful

Comment: Its a remote image url. You have to get ImageData from imageUrl and then set image with imageData

Comment: can you please tape the code line please @MuhammadAdnan

Comment: [self.actuatlitDetail objectForKey:@"poster_240x342"]  this value getting string or url format?

Answer (score 0):

Set Image Path Then Follow this :

```
NSData * imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"Your image url string"]];
UIImageView *imView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData: imageData]];
```

Comment: Chek Your URL DATA

Comment: if Url is not store your imagedata so get this type of error